# How can I access foreign keys in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, foreign-keys

guys!

I have the following code:

```
class Model3D(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    original_Model = models.ForeignKey('Model3D', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    creation_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    stl_File = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='models/stlFiles')
    scad_File = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='models/scadFiles')
    parameter_id = models.ForeignKey('Parameter', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    part_of = models.ForeignKey('Model3D', related_name="part_of_model3d", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    picture_of_model = models.ForeignKey('Pictures', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Pictures(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='models/pictures', null=True)
    model_id = models.ForeignKey('Model3D', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As you can see Model3D has a foreign key relationship to itself because a 3DModel can consist of a e.g. three other 3DModel parts. Therefore the field 'part of' which references Model3D again.
Every Model3D objects has pictures in the Pictures class.

My questions:

**How do I get an Model3D object with all of its part Models?
How do I get all pictures of an Model3D object and all pictures of its part Models?**

I tried so many things regarding select_related but it does not really work.

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Please add what you have already tried and did not work!

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

To get pictures of all nested models:

```
first_model_3d = Model3D.objects.get(id=model_id)
pictures = []
while first_model_3d.part_of:
    pictures.extend([picture for picture in Picture.objects.filter(model_id=first_model_3d)])
    first_model_3d = first_model_3d.part_of
print(pictures)
```

To get nested models from a picture:

```
picture = Picture.objects.get(id=picture_id)
model_3d = picture.model_id
model_3d_list = []
while model_3d:
    model_3d_list = model_3d
    model_3d = model_3d.part_of
print(model_3d_list)
```